# how can i edit the binary data in my edit form in asp.net core mvc

Tags: image, file, input, asp.net-core-mvc, binary-data

the problem I have is the data doesn't show in the input box

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="MovieImage" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="MovieImage" class="form-control" type="file" />
            <span asp-validation-for="MovieImage" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: but when i convert the data the image is shown , what i want is to show the name of the data in the input box; HOW ??

Comment: You can't. The only way to set the value of a file input is by the user to select a file. This is done for security reasons.

Comment: I know that but what i want is when the user want to edit the the movie image so he can see the previous one and if he want to edit it he will, did u get my point ? i see many people doing this but i don't know how. PLEASE some help @Rena

Comment: I think what you want is to store the file path to the property, and use `<img src="/@Property"/>` to display the image. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68478536/11398810

Comment: thank you, but not that what i want, the image is being displayed and the image is transferred from the controller to the edit view and i can display it alone as a static 
object in the page the user can't edit it, but my problem is the image is not being displayed in the input file field so the user can see it there and edit it, i don't know how to do it ??

Comment: i wish you have understood me and got my point

Comment: Hi, as my previous comment said, if you want to display in the input file field, it is impossible....

Comment: but i have seen many websites that they display it in the input file field so how is it impossible !!

Comment: i wish i can take a screenshot of what i mean and show it to you

Comment: And for your information what i mean of i want to put the data in the input file field the data is already uploaded by the user so how is that impossible ? @Rena